# Xen: is possible to see processes of the domU on dom0?

Tags: process, ps, xen

I have installed on a Debian dom0 a paravirtualized domU(Opensuse)
When I use lxc I can see the process with the "translated" uid

for example, on a Slackware lxc "host" I can see the oracle process of centos container

```
pgrep -a oracle
3182 ora_m005_ORACLEDB
4964 ora_pmon_ORACLEDB
4968 ora_clmn_ORACLEDB
4972 ora_psp0_ORACLEDB
4976 ora_vktm_ORACLEDB
4982 ora_gen0_ORACLEDB
4986 ora_mman_ORACLEDB
....
```

On kvm the vms has it own kernel and is "isolated" so the process are not visible from host.
The question is: is possible to see from dom0 the processes of domU vm?
I have tried to launch a program on domU, then i did `pgrep program` from dom0 but return nothing

Comment: Assume I run in my domU my own Operating System that I wrote for myself and that I never told anybody about. How are the Xen authors supposed to be able to write code to detect the processes in my OS if they don't even know that my OS exists?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each DomU has its own kernel, and Dom0 can’t see inside that (beyond what can be inferred from resource use). DomUs don’t have to run the same operating system as Dom0, so the notion of process could even vary from one DomU to another.